# How to find Telerik MVC Grid Name in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

Is there a way to find the Grid Name in the Controller?
I am defining the grid name in my page.

```
<%:
Html.Telerik().Grid<Scout.Server.UI.Web.Mvc.ViewModels.WTO.WTOListViewModel>()
.Name("GridName")
.DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(wto => wto.WTORowID))
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("QueryMyGrid", "GridController")
)
.Columns(columns =>
{
```

I need to find the Grid name in my Action Method.

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult QueryMyGrid(GridCommand command)
{
    var transferOrders = transferOrderService.GetActiveTransferOrdersBySubType(
        typeService.GetSubTypeByMeaning(ModelDefinitions.TypeClassMeaning.ORDER_TYPES,
        ModelDefinitions.TypeMeaning.ORDER_TYPE_TRANSFER_ORDER,
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the Grid name ?
When you use Ajax DataBinding, the Grid will call the specified action (Grid/QueryMyGrid) and  fill the grid with the returned object.
You need to return something like this

```
return View(new GridModel<Scout.Server.UI.Web.Mvc.ViewModels.WTO.WTOListViewModel>(transferOrders));
```